# Using map on an Option[Seq[T]]

Tags: scala

I have an Option[Seq[T]] which, naturally enough may contain a Seq[T] or may indeed by None.

I have been warned away from using .get but how can I use map to return either the intended populated Seq[T] or an empty List() if the Option was None.

I have managed to do it using pattern matching, was wondering if there is a way to use map to achieve the same goal. Thanks!

```
val maybeProducts:Option[Seq[Product]] = {....}

val products:Seq[Product] = {
  maybeProducts match {
    case Some(ps) => ps
    case None     => List()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getOrElse`:

```
maybeProducts.getOrElse(List())
```

Comment: thanks, I was assuming that seeing as how get is considered evil and error prone one should not use its sibling getOrElse either.

Comment: @user3231690 The reason for avoiding `get` is that in the cae of `None` there may be exceptions as there is no defined result. With `getOrElse` you have always a defined return value and no exception is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
val products: Seq[Product] = maybeProducts.getOrElse(List())
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record; another solution is to convert the option to list and then flatten them:

```
maybeProducts.toList.flatten
```